# How do I uncheck the recurring contribution check box by default?

Tags: civicontribute, recurring-contributions

I've searched here and on the CiviCRM forum but haven't been able to find an answer to what I was hoping would be fairly simple.

I want to give people the option of making their contribution recurring, however I don't want the checkbox checked when the form loads I only want the checkbox checked if the user selects it. This is to avoid an embarrassing situation a month down the road when we process their donation again.

[Here's a page with the form in test mode](http://www.thewellspringfoundation.org/donate/test/)

I'm not all that good with code, but did look with Developer Tools and found this:

```
<!-- .tpl file invoked: CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Main.tpl. Call via form.tpl if we have a form in the page. -->
```

I looked at Main.tpl (lines 147-177) but don't understand enough to remove the checked="checked" attribute from the input tag.

```
{if $form.is_recur}
<div class="crm-section {$form.is_recur.name}-section">
<div class="label">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="content">
  {$form.is_recur.html} {$form.is_recur.label} {ts}every{/ts}
{if $is_recur_interval}
    {$form.frequency_interval.html}
  {/if}
  {if $one_frequency_unit}
    {$frequency_unit}
    {else}
    {$form.frequency_unit.html}
  {/if}
  {if $is_recur_installments}
    <span id="recur_installments_num">
    {ts}for{/ts} {$form.installments.html} {$form.installments.label}
    </span>
  {/if}
  <div id="recurHelp" class="description">
    {ts}Your recurring contribution will be processed automatically.{/ts}
    {if $is_recur_installments}
      {ts}You can specify the number of installments, or you can leave the number of installments blank if you want to make an open-ended commitment. In either case, you can choose to cancel at any time.{/ts}
    {/if}
    {if $is_email_receipt}
      {ts}You will receive an email receipt for each recurring contribution.{/ts}
    {/if}
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

{/if}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're in the right place to see what's going on, but the wrong spot to do anything.  The field will arrive in the template fully-rendered, within {$form.is_recur.html} or an equivalent Smarty variable. Editing the template won't help you there.

The form PHP code would allow you to change it, but that's not the best way to go about this: doctoring core CiviCRM code is a bad idea, and while there's a way to set up override files for code files, it's a clunky method.  Besides, you'd have to navigate Quickform, which is a headache in itself.

The better approach to forcing a checkbox checked or not is to use jQuery.  You'll have CSS-style selectors, so you won't need to troll through the templates to see where to alter the box.  You can add your code in one of three places:

1. Somewhere in your WordPress theme
2. In an extension you write, using the [Resource](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Resource+Reference) addScriptFile method to add a script within [hook_civicrm_buildform](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_buildForm) (the preferred method)
3. Using an [.extra.tpl file](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Page+Templates) in your template override directory

Comment: 3 would be my recommendation, then 2, then 1. If you already have an extension built for other purposes, then you could consider implementing a hook on buildForm to set the default. See http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_buildForm

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I was pretty sure that {$form.is_recur.html} was the variable I wanted to look at, I just didn't know where it was defined. I definitely don't want to mess with core files, so I'll try the jQuery route. Thanks.